# Incorrect type warning in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-typing, typechecking

I've created `BaseRepository` class from which I inherit in my specific repositories.
When invoking an `update` method of the `RecipeRepository` I get some strange warning.

Warning:
**Expected type 'SpecificModel' (matched generic type 'T'), got 'SpecificModel' instead**

What am I doing wrong?

### Minimalistic Example:

**- Models**

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Generic

class BaseModel:

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self


class SpecificModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
```

**- Repositories**

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)

class BaseRepository(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, model: T):
        self._model = model

    def update(self, record: T, *args, **kwargs):
        return record.update(*args, **kwargs)


class SpecificRepository(BaseRepository[SpecificModel]):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(SpecificModel)
```

**- Services**

```
class SpecificService:

    def __init__(self, repository: SpecificRepository):
        self._repository = repository

    def update_name(self, record: SpecificModel, name: str):
        # When hovering over `record` I get the warning
        self._repository.update(record, name)
```

### Update #1

I've changed my code from:
`T = TypeVar('T', bound=Type[BaseModel])`
to
`T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)`.
Now I have some type warnings in the constructor of `SpeficRepository`.

**Expected type 'Union[BaseModel, Any]' (matched generic type 'T'), got 'Type[SpecificModel]' instead**

Comment: Your example spans multiple files and depends on third party libraries. These levels of complexity probably aren't relevant to your question and make your code difficult to run. Try to reduce your code to a [mre].

Comment: @Brian updated, I hope it's gonna be easier

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the definition of `T`. Instead of

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Type[BaseModel])
```

you want

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)
```

Ultimately, you want `T` to stand for `BaseModel` and its subclasess, not `type(BaseModel)` (i.e., `type`) and its subclasses.

To diagnosis this issue and others like it, you can use a more complete static type checker like [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/). In this case, mypy gives a much more informative error at the definition `SpecificRepository`:

```
error: Type argument "module.SpecificModel" of "BaseRepository" must be a subtype of "Type[module.BaseModel]"
```

which immediately tells you what the problem is.

Comment: But I think that when I used `T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)`, I also had some warnings, Im gonna check it tommorow and let you know. Thanks for your prompt feedback.

Comment: Hey, I did what you said, but I still get some warnings if you can check out my Update #1.

Comment: What I've realised is that MyPy is not logging it as an issue.